# pywinauto wait for window to appear and send key-press

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to make a small function that will wait until a certain window appear and then send a key-press (alt+i), i've been trying to do this with pywinauto but with no success.
from what i've read in the documantation i can use

```
pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification.Exists()
```

but i just can't understand how to specify what i'm looking for, i can use either the window title or the process name, but can't find a good explanation.

Also, is there a better or easier module to use besides pywinauto? i don't need to do complicated automation, just wait for a window and send some keys.

EDIT

Ok i found a solution, a simple function that loops forever

```
 def auto_accept(*args):
    while True:
        try:
            app = pywinauto.Application()
            app.window_(title='Untitled - Notepad').SetFocus()
            app.window_(title='Untitled - Notepad').TypeKeys("{1}{2}{3}")
        except (pywinauto.findwindows.WindowNotFoundError, pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError):
            pass
```

But now i always get a warning like "2015-07-13 12:18:02,887 INFO: Typed text to the Notepad: {1}{2}{3}" and i can't filter them out using the warnings module, is there another way to filter\disable them? it's an issue since when i create an exe using py2exe, after the program is closed it tells me there are errors, but the only errors are the warning i get from sendkeys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `wait/wait_not` methods for `WindowSpecification` object:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="win32").start('executable')
app.WindowSpecification.wait('enabled').type_keys('%i') # % - alt, ^ - ctrl
```

`WindowSpecification` can be set with more details:

```
app.window(title='Title', class_name='#32770')
```

All possible parameters for `window()` method are the same as [for find_elements function](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html#pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements) (this low-level function is not recommended for direct usage).

For long operation you can set timeout for single wait: `wait('enabled', timeout=20)` or set timeout for every `wait` globally: `Timings.window_find_timeout = 10`

---

EDIT: call this code after `import pywinauto` to disable logging:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('pywinauto')
logger.level = logging.WARNING # or higher
```

Logger levels:

```
Level Numeric value 
CRITICAL 50 
ERROR 40 
WARNING 30 
INFO 20 
DEBUG 10 
NOTSET 0
```

Comment: Thanks but i found a solution that works, on another note, how can i disable the warnings that i recive when sending keystrokes? i always get a warning like "2015-07-13 12:18:03,100 INFO: Typed text to the Notepad: {1}{2}{3}" and i can't filter them out using the warning module.

Comment: Because it's logging module stuff. Updated answer to cover that.

Comment: pywinauto 0.5.1 will have a documented shortcut: `pywinauto.actionlogger.disable()` Thanks for the use case.

Comment: Is there a way to wait forever? My dialog is created externally. Currently using a very large value.

Comment: Another way is much more complicated. You need a hook on `WM_CREATE` event. This can't be explained in a few words. We plan to implement nice hook API in pywinauto, but ETA is unknown.